# pandas - combining datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 datasets I am trying to combine with pandas.

The first type dataset is like this. It has multiple index values for postcode as there are multiple restaurants in the dataframe (I am trying to give those restaurants more demographic context).

```
   postcode      restaurants           
   3793          3,577
   3477             21
   3971             26
   3222          7,519
   3747          3,859
```

Second is like this (mainly postcodes versus one or maybe two attributes, key to one value pair.

```
    postcode          burgers                  
    2640              38064  
  
    
    postcode       soda     
    3000           23715
    3002             854
    3003             780
    3004              35
    3006            3288>
```

These have been simplified.

When using concat or merge with pandas, I am receiving errors of

```
ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned
```

With this code

```
result = pd.concat(frames,join='outer')
```

How can I simply join these datasets into one? What mistake am I making?

#### Expected Output based on a comment

Basically looking for burgers and sodas to be placed into the data frame as a value against the postcode.

example

```
    postcode      pop growth    burgers    soda   address       
        3793          3,577      123123    1231   AbyRoad
        3793          3,577      12351      5151   northst
        3971             26      6666      7777   northunder abby
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that postcode column is the (only) index for each of the dataframes. You need to run this for all.

Next, if you do have all the dataframes with index as postcode. Please put them in a list called frames (list of dataframes) and use the following code.

```
dfList = [df1, df2, df3]
frames = [df.set_index('postcode') for df in dfList]
pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

If that doesnt work, maybe try this -

```
from functools import reduce

frames = [df.reset_index() for df in dfList] #reset the indexes and add dfs into a list
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='postcode'), frames)
```

Comment: ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
 Next error : /

Comment: This means that some of your 'postcode' columns are of different datatype. Can you change each of them with ```df['postcode']=df['postcode'].astype(int)```